Manhwa in which the Empress female lead helped the Emperor male lead escape her father when he was young
Main plot points:

The female lead is blonde and is the Empress.
Her husband, the Emperor, hates her and, in the manhua, got a concubine.
Her father abuses her.
Later in the story, we find out (when they were kids) that the Empress helped the Emperor to escape her father, who was trying to kill the Emperor, but the Emperor doesn't know it and is trying to find the person who helped him when he was young.
The Empress remembers saving the Emperor.
The Empress is misunderstood by the Emperor, who thinks she is a spy for her father.
The Empress tries secretly helping the Emperor.
It's on NAVER WEBTOON.


Does this contain any sci-fi or fantasy elements?

It's Wished You Were Dead, sorry.

King Karloi of Croisen finds himself at odds with his position in life. His wife’s father, Duke Deluah, is angling for the throne, and as an outsider to the family, Karloi fears for his position. His frustrations have affected his marriage, though he finds himself questioning his cold approach to his wife, Evonne. He may no longer recognize her, but Evonne saved his life long ago, and was his first love. This is but one of many secrets Evonne bears the weight of, having fallen victim to a curse that prevents her from telling any secrets...


No worries! In 48 hours' time you should be able to mark this answer as accepted, and if anyone in the future comes here searching for the same manhua, they'll find this question and know what the answer is.

The Baka-Updates page has this tagged with 'Fantasy,' 'Curse/s' and 'Spell/s,' suggesting that it is on-topic here.
